# Steam: Change Store Game Hover from Image to Description

Tags: steam

A recent update made it so that when you hover over a game in the Steam Store (not ones like the "Popular new releases" or "Upcoming"), instead of giving a description of the game, it'll give you images. Sure, this is good if you want to see what it looks like, but personally I dislike it because:

-It uses up more internet and is slow to preview

-It can be redundant for, say, games in the store slideshow, which already shows pictures (Hovering over it shows the pictures in the hover box as well as in the preview)

-It doesn't provide a description of the game and story, which can be much more important

-For some games, *you don't want* the pictures to show...

So my question is simple: Is there a way to change it from showing images to showing the description?

An example is this:

[image]